# TableLayoutPanel scrollbars bugged at specific amount of rows?

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, tablelayoutpanel

I use a TableLayouPanel, programmatically add rows of 50px height each. TLP y-size is 217 px, so **adding 5 rows** results in a vertical scrollbar but also a **horizontal scrollbar**.

When I add **another row** - still vertical scrollbar - the **horizontal scrollbar disappears**.

Tried to change the TLP's size to anything between 200 and 250, stays the same.

How do I remove this behaviour as any number of rows but 5 works fine?

Code from designer and adding rows:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
tableLayoutPanel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 3;
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 50F));
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 50F));
tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(709, 217);


tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.RemoveAt(0);
for (int i = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i].Dispose();
}
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 50));
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 0, i);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 1, i);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 2, i);
}
if (!tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Visible){ //false for 5
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize, 0));
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 0, inp.Count);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 1, inp.Count);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 2, inp.Count);
}
```

**tl;dr why is there a horizontal scrollbar with 5 rows and how to make content fit outer control again so there is none?**

---

Thought of fixing this by adding another row and deleting it again, but since `TableLayoutPanel` doesn't give a fck, the last row automatically takes up the "remaining" space of the removed row...atleast that's what my current progress looks like, not sure if I should change everything to `DataGridView`

Comment: Not related to the main problem - but did you consider to use `DataGridView` for displaying dynamic data in "row-columns" way

Comment: @Fabio Sadly, no. However I never want wo use `TableLayoutPanel` ever again, I had so many problems with it already and I'm not even working on the biggest part of my project because all the time I gotta fix some layout shit caused by TLP. Thanks for recommending `DataGridView` for future projects, don't know if it's worth to switch anymore though (regarding how many bugs I ran into yet: probably, but of course you always hope "this is the last one, everything works perfectly fine if you resolve this")

Comment: @Fabio tried replacing the TableLayoutPanel with DataGridView but had somewhat unresolvable difficulties creating my own DataGridViewColumn. Back to trying with TableLayoutPanel

Comment: Why you need to create own `DataGridViewColumn`? What kind of data you want display there?

Comment: @Fabio another Grid, one I don't have to change tho, so I tried to make a `TableLayoutPanel`-`DataGridViewColumn`, as I already did the code for it and that grid has to display labels and a textbox, otherwise I would have had to make a `DataGridView`-`DataGridViewColumn` with another column for the labels. And even then I'd have to adjust dozens of things I already took care of with `TableLayoutPanel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of different things and found a solution working for me:

> ```
> tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.RemoveAt(0);
> for (int i = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
>     tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i].Dispose();
> }
> ```

became

```
int i;  
while ((i = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count) >= 2) {
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[--i].Dispose();      
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[--i].Dispose();      
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[--i].Dispose();  
}   
while (tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Count > 0) {         
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.RemoveAt(tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Count - 1);
}
```

and (empty row with variable size to keep the last row's size if there are less rows than space before a scrollbar is necessary)

> ```
> if (!tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Visible){ //false for 5
>     tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize, 0));
>     tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 0, inp.Count);
>     tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 1, inp.Count);
>     tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 2, inp.Count);
> }
> ```

became

<strike>tableLayoutPanel1.Update();</strike> //not <strike>sure if</strike> necessary <strike>yet</strike>

```
if (!tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Visible) {
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize, 0));
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 0, inp.Count);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 1, inp.Count);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 2, inp.Count);
} else if (tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible) {
    if (tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Count != inp.Count) {
        tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(0, inp.Count).Dispose();
        tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(1, inp.Count).Dispose();
        tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(2, inp.Count).Dispose();
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.RemoveAt(inp.Count);
    } else {
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize, 0));
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 0, inp.Count);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 1, inp.Count);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), 2, inp.Count);
        tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(0, inp.Count).Dispose();
        tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(1, inp.Count).Dispose();
        tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(2, inp.Count).Dispose();
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.RemoveAt(inp.Count);
    }
}
```

*For anyone wondering: `inp.Count` is the amount of actually added non-empty rows.*

It might be possible to reformat and shorten this, as it looks redundant, but I worked long enough to get it to work at all, should be fine for now.